# tmux errors running bash commands due to path

Tags: command-line, bash, paths, tmux

When I run `$tmux` and open an instance of a tmux session and try to run a command such as `ls` I receive the following error:

```
∆ ls
Command 'ls' is available in the following places
 * /bin/ls
 * /usr/bin/ls
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin:/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
ls: command not found
```

If I try to source my .bashrc I receive errors as well.

I currently do not have a tmux.conf file in my home directory and installed tmux with `sudo apt install tmux`

`apt show tmux` yields:

```
∆ apt show tmux -a
Package: tmux
Version: 3.0a-2ubuntu0.2
Priority: optional
Section: admin
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Romain Francoise <rfrancoise@debian.org>
...
```

Comment: Try creating a ~/.tmux.conf file containing the line `set-option -g default-shell /bin/bash`

Comment: - so in my home directory I made a `.tmux.conf` file
- I put `set-option -g default-shell /bin/bash` as well as trying setting as `/usr/bin/bash` (my `which bash` yields `/usr/bin/bash`

after trying both and relaunching tmux both times I still would get the same error.  I can run `/usr/bin/ls` in tmux but not `ls`

Comment: any follow up with this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a ~/.tmux.conf file and add this line inside `set-option -g update-environment "PATH"`

After that run `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf` to load the new config.

It should solve the issue, but to be sure you can run `echo $PATH` both inside and outside of tmux and see if the paths are the same.